# factory_boy: add several dependent objects

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm using factory_boy to replace fixtures in a Django app. I have a Product model that should have many Offers and Merchants.

```
#models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Merchant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField()

class Offer(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I want a factory that creates a Product with several Merchants and several Offers.

```
#factories.py
import random
from models import Offer, Merchant, Product

class OfferFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Offer

    product = factory.SubFactory(ProductFactory)
    price = random.randrange(0, 50000, 1)/100.0


class MerchantFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Merchant

    product = factory.SubFactory(ProductFactory)
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'Merchant %s' % n)
    url = factory.sequence(lambda n: 'www.merchant{n}.com'.format(n=n))

 class ProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Product 

    name = "test product"
    offer = factory.RelatedFactory(OfferFactory, 'product')
    offer = factory.RelatedFactory(OfferFactory, 'product') # add a second offer
    offer = factory.RelatedFactory(OfferFactory, 'product') # add a third offer
    merchant = factory.RelatedFactory(MerchantFactory, 'product')
    merchant = factory.RelatedFactory(MerchantFactory, 'product') # add a second merchant
    merchant = factory.RelatedFactory(MerchantFactory, 'product') # add a third merchant
```

But when I use ProductFactory to create a Product, it only has one offer and one merchant.

```
In [1]: from myapp.products.factories import ProductFactory

In [2]: p = ProductFactory()

In [3]: p.offer_set.all()
Out[3]: [<Offer: $39.11>]
```

**How do I set up a ProductFactory to have more than one dependent of a particular type?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to specify the number of related objects in parent factory:

#### models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ContactPerson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='contacts')
```

#### factories.py

```
class CompanyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker('company')

    class Meta:
        model = Company

    @factory.post_generation
    def add_contacts(self, create, how_many, **kwargs):
        # this method will be called twice, first time how_many will take the value passed
        # in factory call (e.g., add_contacts=3), second time it will be None
        # (see factory.declarations.PostGeneration#call to understand how how_many is populated)
        # ContactPersonFactory is therefore called +1 times but somehow we get right amount of objs
        at_least = 1
        if not create:
            return
        for n in range(how_many or at_least):
            ContactPersonFactory(contact=self)



class ContactPersonFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker('first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = ContactPerson
```

#### tests.py

```
company = CompanyFactory(company_name='ACME ltd', add_contacts=4)
print(repr(company.name), len(company.contacts.all()))
company = CompanyFactory(company_name='ACME ltd')
print(repr(company.name), len(company.contacts.all()))

---
'ACME ltd' 4
'ACME ltd' 1
```

---

If you are ok with always just one child, [the docs solution](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#reverse-dependencies-reverse-foreignkey) works well:

#### models.py

```
class CompanyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker('company')
    whatever_really = factory.RelatedFactory('my_app.factories.ContactPersonFactory', 'contact')

    class Meta:
        model = Company
```

note the full path to the related factory.

#### tests.py

```
company = CompanyFactory(company_name='ACME ltd')
print(repr(company.name), len(company.contacts.all()))
---
'ACME ltd' 1
```

---

#### versions used

```
$ pip freeze | egrep 'factory|Faker|Django'
Django==2.0.4
factory-boy==2.10.0
Faker==0.8.13
$ python -V
Python 3.6.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class ProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Product 

    name = "test product"

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        num = kwargs.pop('offer_num', 1)
        attrs = cls.attributes(create=True, extra=kwargs)
        product = cls._generate(True, attrs)
        for n in range(num)
            OfferFactory(product=product)
        return product
```

ProductFactory(offer_num=4) this will create 4 related offers.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure:

```
class ProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Product 

    name = "test product"
    offer1 = factory.RelatedFactory(OfferFactory, 'product')
    offer2 = factory.RelatedFactory(OfferFactory, 'product') # add a second offer
    offer3 = factory.RelatedFactory(OfferFactory, 'product') # add a third offer
    merchant1 = factory.RelatedFactory(MerchantFactory, 'product')
    merchant2 = factory.RelatedFactory(MerchantFactory, 'product') # add a second merchant
    merchant3 = factory.RelatedFactory(MerchantFactory, 'product') # add a third"
```

Comment: Could someone please explain? I get that Python has names not variables, but why wouldn't `offer` just be re-pointed to the output of the next execution of `factory.RelatedFactory` as the OP intended? Why does `factory.RelatedFactory` have to be assigned to something to execute?